# Searching for the largest open space in an array (C)?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I have an array of characters, which may look like:

1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1

I need to develop a search algorithm to find the best-fit hole in the array. I CANNOT use a linear search. (The problem is...I can't think of any other way to do it).

Basically, if the input into my program is 3 bytes long, I need an function which would find the three 0's in the array and use that spot to insert the data.

Comment: "cannot use linear search" sounds like homework?

Comment: If you're just given that array, you have to do a linear search it seems. If you're the one who _adds_ the values to the array, you can keep a record of empty spaces without needing to search at all.

Comment: It is... I can do it using linear search, nothing complex. But I just can't figure out any other POSSIBLE ways of doing it. I though about binary search, but it wouldn't be applicable in this case...hmm idk

Comment: "I CANNOT use a linear search" - what do you mean by that? Do you mean that the complexity must be less than linear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the array is given to you as is (you didn't create it), since you know the size of the hole you need, you can jump by size and look forward and back when you hit a `0` to see if there's room.

If you're trying to find a hole for 3 bytes and `a[0] == 1` then you know it won't fit in `a[0] -> a[2]`. Skip ahead to `a[3]` and see if that's a `0`; if it is, look forward and back to see if there's room for 3 bytes.

This is only slightly better than the brute-force approach of going through the list start - finish, but it is better.

Comment: Isn't it still a linear search?

Comment: By definition, no, because you're not visiting every element. Edit: Except in the case where size is 1, of course. Usually this type of homework problem has the student inserting into a list with some sort of requirement that creates holes; the classic example is putting groups of people on an airplane in adjacent seats.

Comment: This is very similar to the [Boyer-Moore string searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm); Boyer-Moore is generally held to be linear, but with a very low constant.

Comment: Yes, it's O(n) time (it grows linearly with the size of the set) ... but it's not a *linear search*.

Answer (score 0):

You can index it before start.
Before do any search, you can scan array and create list of structures like:

```
struct SuitablePlace {
   int pos;
   ine len;
};
```

Then fill it, sort by len field, and when you get request of region with specific size,
you can use binary search to find out suitable place.

Answer (score 0):

For example, like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char data[]={1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1};

    int dataSize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(char);
    int maxPos=-1;
    int maxLen=0;
    int pos;

    for(pos=0; pos<dataSize;){
        int skip = pos + maxLen;
        if(skip >= dataSize)break;
        if(data[pos] == 1){
            if(skip + 1 < dataSize && data[skip + 1] == 1){//add skip proc for value of 1
                pos = skip + 2;
                continue;
            }
            ++pos;
        } else {
            int len;
            if(data[skip] == 1){
                pos = skip + 1;
                continue;
            }
            for(len = 1; pos + len < dataSize && data[pos+len] == 0;++len);
            if(maxLen < len){
                maxPos = pos;
                maxLen = len;
            }
            pos += len + 1;
        }
    }
    if(maxPos == -1){
        printf("no space\n");
    } else {
        printf("The largest space is the area of length %d from position %d.\n", maxLen, maxPos);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**result**

```
The largest space is the area of length 3 from position 6.
```

Comment: It  skip search unlike liner.

Comment: what do antonpug and you say defining liner search  ? ex)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search

Answer (score 0):

So you are given an array of length *n* and a number *k*, and asked to find the best fit hole in the array that is as near to *k* as possible, but no smaller.

With no prior information about the array, and no guarantee about the relationship between *k* and *n*, you must spend *O(n/k)* time searching the array to find an appropriate hole. Why?

Think of it this way: a priori, you have *n - k* locations where your best fit hole might start. If you query a single element in the array, the most information you can possibly extract is that *k* locations in the array cannot work:

```
n = 12, k = 3
array: [ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]
                        ^-(query here, find it is occupied)  
array: [ ? ][ X ][ X ][ X ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]
                  Now you know the locations with X's cannot fit your data.
                  However, you can't know anything more than that.
```

From this you can see that no matter your search algorithm or the order in which you query the array, you will need *O(n/k)* accesses to determine where any hole is, let alone a best fit.

**P.S.** There is also some confusion about the term "linear search". To most, that is equivalent to saying that the algorithm takes linear time -- and your algorithm MUST take linear time. If "linear search" to you means a sequential item-by-item search through the array, then you can improve *slightly* on *O(n)*, but no more so than *k*. If *k* is supposed to be a constant for the problem, than it drops out and you are still left with *O(n)*.